# Check if Magento cart is empty using Javascript?

Tags: php, cart, javascript

So I need to check if the cart on my magento site is empty or not.
I can do this using php like this:

```
<?php
    $count = $this->helper('checkout/cart')->getSummaryCount();
    if($count==0){
      echo '<a href="#" data-url="checkout/cart/add/product/59/form_key/' . Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey() . '" class="btn btn-success ac-button-top add-to-cart">Order</a>';
    } else {
      echo '<a href="' . $this->getUrl('checkout/cart') .'" class="btn btn-success ac-button-top add-to-cart">CHECKOUT</a>';
    }
?>
```

However, the problem is that using PHP it will get cached.
So in order for the button to change you'd have to refresh the cache.
So I was wondering if there is any way to do this check in javascript instead of PHP as I can't think of a way to do it?